# Generate PDF using Ireport with JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I want to generate a PDF report using JasperReports with JSP

and this is my code

```
<% 
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:personnel","user","password");

try {
   File reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("//reports//rapport_absences.jasper"));
    Map h = new HashMap();

    byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(),h,cn);

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",  "inline; filename=report.pdf ");
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outStream.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();

}catch (Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

but it give me a blank PDF, although when I run the report from Ireport it runs well and get the data but from jsp it get a blank pdf

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: I don't know ... I have this problem too ... the errors doesn't show in the console ... it shows only if there is a SQL error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as always I found the soulution my self since now one could help and here is it I let it here if any one needs it in the future

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page contentType="application/pdf" %>
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>



<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*" %>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>


<%
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
Connection cn =    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:personnel","charif","charif123");

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",  "inline; filename=report.pdf ");
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport("D:\\ISTA\\Projet_Stage\\GestionPersonnel\\web\\reports\\rapport_absences.jasper",
new HashMap(),
cn);


JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print,    
response.getOutputStream());

%>
```